# get chunk of a list in bash

Tags: bash, list, shell

I need to divide in 3, a list similar to this with over 3000 lines. I need to make the division in such a way where I can specify somthing like:

1. chunk -> from words starting with "a" until words starting with "e" (including all words that start with letter "e").
2. chunk -> from words starting with "f", until words starting with "mj" (including all words that start with "mj").
3. chunk -> from words starting with "mk", until words starting with "z".

Example input:

```
about
block
echo
far
maps
mjalgo
mjprou
mksomething
november
opshacom
oscar
softball
zorro
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? I don't need one command to do it all, I just need to know how to write 1 command per chunk needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `perl -ne 'print if /^c/ .. /^dd/'`?

Comment: Just tried this one, works perfect! :) Thank you!!! melpomene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a range type regex, like `/^c/  -- /^dd/` you can use sed on a sorted file:

```
$ sed -nE '/^c/,/^dd/p' file.txt
caccount@example.com
daccount@example.com
ddaccount@domain.com
```

Or perl:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /^c/ .. /^dd/' file.txt
caccount@example.com
daccount@example.com
ddaccount@domain.com
```

Or awk:

```
$ awk '/^c/,/^dd/' file.txt
caccount@example.com
daccount@example.com
ddaccount@domain.com
```

---

Based on the new post:

If you wish to group by different regex matches, `awk` is your best bet (or multiple runs of `sed` `grep` etc)

Example:

```
$ cat file.txt
about
block
echo
far
maps
mjalgo
mjprou
mksomething
november
opshacom
oscar
softball
zorro
```

You can do:

```
$ awk '/^[a-e]/               {print $0>"f1.txt"; next}
     /^[f-k]/ || /^m[a-j]/    {print $0>"f2.txt"; next}
     /^m[k-z]/ || /^[n-z]/    {print $0>"f3.txt"; next}
     ' file.txt
```

Then you have your 3 buckets in 3 different files:

```
for fn in f{1..3}.txt; do
    sort "$fn"
    echo "==="
done
```

Prints:

```
about
block
blood
echo
===
maps
mjalgo
mjprou
===
mksomething
november
opshacom
oscar
softball
zorro
===
```

If the input is sorted the sorting of each file is not necessary. If you have `gawk` vs POSIX awk, you can sort the lines internally.

Comment: Wouldn't this grep '^[cd][a-d]' file.txt exclude for instance the names that are "craccount" or similar? There are ~3000 accounts in that list. Basically, I need to divide that list by three. Starting from 1 account until another account, then from that last account to a another account, and lately from that last account until the end.

Comment: Aww -- yes -- use the range version.

Comment: Yeah...that wont fit what I need, since i need a whole chunk of the list. I guess I'm not explaining clear enough, but think of a very long list of users, that you need to divide in 3 pieces. From users that start with "a" to users that start with "e" (included), then from users that start with "f" to users that start with "ml" (included), latetly from users that start with "mm" until the end of the list. I'm trying to explain as good as i can but I understand that I'm not being really clear, sorry.

Comment: I just saw your latest comment :) I think it is working as I needed!!! I'll test it a little bit :) thank you!!!

Comment: `awk` or `perl` are your best bets to group by several different regex's. Expand your example and I can show you how.

Comment: Ok. I tried to describe better the need. Hopefully this time I was able to explain myself more clear. Really sorry for my first bad explanaition of the request.

Comment: great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '$0>="c" && $0<"dd"' file
caccount@example.com
daccount@example.com
```

Comment: Thank you! this one also works perfectly :) I see that it excludes the "dd", but it will work fine forme as it does includes the "c" from the output.

Comment: If you want the `dd`: `... && $0<"de" ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with csplit

```
csplit infile /^f/ /^mk/
```